# TemplatedConfigLoader in register_config_loader not replacing patterns in catalog.yml (kedro)

Tags: python, config, hook, catalog, kedro

I am using kedro to manage some data, for which I have a number of dataset CSVs in the same location. As described [here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_kedro_project_setup/02_configuration.html#templating-configuration), I should be able to store the filepath to this location in a globals.yml file, and use the ${...} syntax in my catalog, but I can't seem to make it work.

More specifically, as a simple example, I have a catalog.yml that looks like this:

```
dataset:
  type: ${csv}
  filepath: ${directory}/Data/dataset.csv
```

and a globals.yml file in my conf/base folder:

```
csv: "pandas.CSVDataSet"
directory: "file/path/to/directory"
```

I have also updated the register_config_loader in my project's hooks.py, as described in the docs:

```
@hook_impl
    def register_config_loader(self, conf_paths: Iterable[str]) -> ConfigLoader:
        return TemplatedConfigLoader(
            conf_paths,
            globals_pattern="*globals.yml"
        )
```

If I'm correct, what I think this should do is replace the ${directory} in my catalog with file/path/to/directory. However, when I run `kedro jupyter notebook` and try running `catalog.load('dataset')`, I get the error:

```
DataSetError: An exception occurred when parsing config for DataSet `dataset`:
Class `${csv}` not found.
```

I think the hook is not replacing the ${...} instances correctly - how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```py
    @hook_impl
    def register_config_loader(
        self, conf_paths: Iterable[str]
    ) -> TemplatedConfigLoader:
        return TemplatedConfigLoader(conf_paths, globals_pattern="*globals.yml")
```

should work. You need to provide the glob to your `globals.yml`. Default is `None`.

Comment: Hi Lim, thanks for your answer. It looks like my original implementation does already have the `globals_pattern` argument set to "*globals.yml", which is why I am confused why it isn't detecting/making use of it... is there a way of viewing the resulting global dictionary prepared by the `TemplatedConfigLoader`, e.g. from the KedroContext?

Comment: Ah hmm sorry I misread. I checked out a brand new repo and did exactly what you did and it works. You can inspect `context._config_loader._arg_dict`. The globals yml gets merged into that. You can also try `context._config_loader.get("*globals.yml")` and see if it returns anything

Comment: `context.config_loader.get("*globals.yml") does return a dictionary of the contents of globals.yml, as expected. I've just noticed that the object returned when I call `context.config_loader` is of type `kedro.config.config.ConfigLoader`, i.e. not a TemplatedConfigLoader - perhaps there is a problem with the hook?

Comment: @MichaelCole unlikely... I have just created an empty directory with your exact example above and everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of `kedro >= 0.18`, `register_config_loader`  no longer works.

https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/blob/b23d8033f178e937e3ce9e7320fbb16da7281b4a/RELEASE.md#configuration-loaders

Instead, do something like

```py
CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
    "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
    "globals_dict": {
      # custom logic
    },
}
```

in the `settings.py` to dynamically change the globals.